# Refresh chart value on certain duration

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Currently i have inserted the graph in my website using Chart.js. Am trying to refresh the chart value on certain duration. Someone please advice me

```js
new Chart('chart-' + index, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [ "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12" ],
    datasets: [{
      backgroundColor: utils.transparentize(presets.red),
      borderColor: presets.red,
      data: [ 23, 12, 24, 0, 34, 33, 29, 33, 29 ], // this value will be select from database       
      label: 'Label',
      fill: boundary
    }]
  },
});
```

This graph should refreshed automatically on certain duration data :[23,12,24,0,34,33,29,33,29 this value will update once it got refreshed.

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should be specific and your relevant code should be [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout to execute a function and update your chart
Assign setTimeout from your data

Like this

```
 var x = 0;
 function ref() {
   setIntervel(ref, array[x]);
   x++;
   // codes to update chart
 }
```

You will have to write codes according to your need